# zsh: no matches found

Tags: command-line, zsh

It seems I have some zsh misconfiguration. I use youtube-dl regular to download videos. But since a few days, I get this error

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkd6JkfI4yk
zsh: no matches found: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkd6JkfI4yk
```

I did not change anything with my zsh configuration. Why do I get this error message and how can I make it work again?

FYI I don’t have oh-my-zsh installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the `?` and `=` using backslashes:

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch\?v\=mkd6JkfI4yk
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but why is this happening now? In bash it works fine.

Comment: @SebastianSemmler `?` is a globbing pattern for any one character. In Bash, if no matching files are found, the `?` is treated as a literal `?` character, whereas in ZSH, no such exception is made. Thus, e.g. if we create the file `test-x.txt`, then `echo test-?.txt` will output `test-x.txt` in both Bash and ZSH, but if we delete the file, then Bash outputs `test-?.txt`, whereas ZSH complains that it can't find any files with matching names: `no matches found`.

Answer (score 4):

Wrapping in quotes also works

```
youtube-dl "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkd6JkfI4yk"
```