# Pasting UTF-8 into Terminal (zsh) does something weird

Tags: keyboard, copy-paste, textedit, utf-8

***Is there an environmental setting that makes pasting text into Terminal work differently from typing it in directly?***

I reported this as a bug, but maybe there's some environmental setting.  After the first failure, I put the command in a script to send them as a demo, but it worked when I ran the script.

The command is

```
echo "ΕΡΤΥΙΟΚΗΑΖΧΒΝΜ" | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]
```

The string is Greek letters typed with the keyboard set to Greek.  Behavior is the same whether I use the keys and fingers or the Keyboard Viewer and mouse.

locale is `en_US.UTF-8` and TextEdit is set to always use UTF-8.  I put the command in TextEdit, copied it to clipboard, and pasted into Terminal (with stdin containing the Greek string).  Result:

```
zsh: no matches found: [:upper:]
```

If I swap the classes, I get

```
zsh: no matches found: [:lower:]
```

If I save the file from TextEdit, give it a `chmod 700`, and run it, it does what it should, no error message.

If I change the command to convert Greek to Latin with

```
echo "ΕΡΤΥΙΟΚΗΑΖΧΒΝΜ" | tr "ΕΡΤΥΙΟΚΗΑΖΧΒΝΜ" "EPTYIOKHAZXBNM"
```

(instead of using classes), then it works pasted or in script.

If I type `echo "" | od -xc` and paste the Greek between the quote marks, I see that the characters are not ASCII.  So Paste from clipboard must be doing something **other than** changing the characters.

NOTES:

(1) the tr command fails **only** when pasted and it contains neither `=` nor `?`, so escaping those is not a solution, and this is this is not a duplicate of [zsh: no matches found](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254014/zsh-no-matches-found)

(2) It's plausible that zsh might treat [:xxx:] differently from bash, but what we have here is zsh/Terminal treating pasted text differently from typed in text.

Comment: You need to put quotes around `[:upper:]` and `[:lower:]`. Sequences in square brackets are shell wildcard expressions. bash ignores this if there are no matching filenames, but zsh throws an error. Use moar quotes! See [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411595/ssh-keygen-r-saying-wrongly-no-matches-found) and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254014/zsh-no-matches-found).

Comment: In the script, I did not add quotes, and it still worked.  It also worked when I typed it in instead of pasting (again without quotes).  In other words, the SAME character string behaved differently when pasted in.

Comment: 1) Did you *try* quoting the arguments to `tr` to see if the error goes away (hint: it will)? 2) `?` and `[ ]` are both wildcards, so the same principles apply to both. Also, the other previous Q I linked is specifically about `[ ]` causing this error. 3) The script version is probably running under bash instead of zsh; as for why it works differently with copy&paste, there must be some other difference but I can't tell from here what it might be. C'mon, dude, show some initiative in figuring things out for yourself -- I'm not going to hold your hand every step of the way!

Comment: I'll give that a try, but with no bang line in the script, it should run with the default shell, not with bash.  Note that when the command is typed in to zsh, also _without_ quotes, it worked.

Comment: Scripts without shebang lines usually execute under /bin/sh, and in macOS that's actually bash (in sh compatibility mode). Also, while leaving those arguments unquoted will not cause an error in bash, it may still fail catastrophically if there are any files that match the bracket expression. QUOTE THEM!

Comment: Yes: with no bang line in a script, Terminal runs it in bash instead of the user's default shell.  I consider THAT a bug.

Comment: If there is no bang line, scripts are executed by /bin/sh. This is standard behavior (and logical if you think of it, unless you want to introduce surprising errors if a user has the default shell set to csh for instance).

Comment: I would support this being closed as not useful, not clear how to reproduce this, but I don’t see it as as duplicate of any existing questions. It needs triage and some basic troubleshooting IMO.

Comment: Some more insights into the "which shell is used to execute a text file which doesn't include a bang bath" can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373223/which-shell-interpreter-runs-a-script-with-no-shebang).

Comment: I put this on hold again, as right now the question is a mixture of things you tried and wrong assumptions which make it nearly impossible to provide answers (because the correct contradicts your assumptions). Please edit the question to focus on a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Whatever.  the issue is here and the explanation..

Comment: You compare running `tr` with unquoted and with quoted parameters, and wonder why the first version leads to error. The answer is simple: parameters need to be quoted, as explained in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254014/zsh-no-matches-found (and the man page and practically any shell introduction text).

Comment: Which is kind of obvious because for the shell, there is no difference between typing and pasting. And which is easy to verify: typing `echo "ΕΡΤΥΙΟΚΗΑΖΧΒΝΜ" | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]`  in `zsh` returns `zsh: no matches found: [:upper:]`.

Comment: I did not compare those until after it was pointed out that un-banged scripts don't run in the default shell—which I STILL consider a design error.

Comment: Which brings us back to the reason why the question currently is on hold :-)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no environmental quick fix to strip all possible characters from your pasteboard that could cause issues when not escaped and pasted into the `zsh` shell.

You will want to be careful about character sets, run [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on your scripts to fix them and be careful when pasting.

- [ssh-keygen -R saying (wrongly) no matches found](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/411595/)
- [zsh: no matches found](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/254014/)
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22no+matches+found%22+zsh

All manner of things that look normal to someone from `bash` Experience can and will trip you up with `zsh` - enough that switching back to `bash` might be the quick fix in your case.

Comment: The "quick fix" is obviously to not paste things that don't work in zsh.  And I usually write scripts with bang lines.  this was just a "quick & dirty" to demo what appeared to be a bug.  I can't agree with the decision to run an "unbanged" script in bash "to avoid surprises"  when obviously, this did NOT avoid the surprise.